# Create a stresstest for a site

Tags: php, web, stress-testing, simulate

I have a site made using zend framework (not really important but to be precise).

I need a software/script/anything to create some kind of stress test to see how many users it can support.

I must simulate users navigating between pages, nothing too fancy.

Can anyone suggest me something?

Also it would be nice if I could create some kind of dependency on the hardware resources.

Comment: http://blog.olenepal.org/index.php/archives/300 using apache benchmark ( ab ) and JMeter

Comment: I used a free website/service about a year ago that pulled together very nice statistics such as access times, load times for up to 50 simultaneous users. (more users was not free). I apologize though, I can not remember the name of the site and my google-fu is not strong with me today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the other answers will get you a very basic level of load testing, but in general they don't exercise the server realistically because they don't request all the other resources (images, css, etc) on the page.  If that is ok for you, then they are a good place to start. Just know that you'll only be testing a portion of the system.  If you want to more accurately simulate the expected traffic, then you'll need to move up to a more sophisticated load testing tool. If you have zero budget for software, there is JMeter and OpenSTA. With a meager budget, you can use the services from BrowserMob or LoadStorm for simple load tests. If you need more than than, the you'll need to look to the more sophisticated load testing tools (such as our product - Web Performance Load Tester).

Answer (score 3):

If you're running on an apache webserver, take a look at [apache bench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use apache bench (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) or siege -my favourite- (http://freshmeat.net/projects/siege/) for testing